# Smart ways to handle long texts

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, docx

I have a **.docx** document that is **28 pages long**, it contains headings, sub-headings, italic text, bold text and some lists.

I have to display small portions of this text in a React Native app that should divide this document by "**category**".

For example, I have an *"Heading 1*" link, when tapping on this link, the user should see  the list of sub-headings contained in the Heading 1 section of said document.

This list contains links (such as "*Sub-heading 1*", "*Sub-heading-2*", etc.) that should redirect the user to the small portions of the document under sub-heading.

I couldn't come up with smart and faster ways to handle this problem, in fact, the only methods I could come up with are:

- **Hard code** the text in the react native app (which wouldn't be a problem if the document was short)
- **Using an external .docx file viewer** (but this isn't a proper solution)

---

Is there any **smarter** (and possibly easier) way to organize .docx documents so that I can use the text inside the app, while keeping its format?

Comment: Have you though about converting your document into an HTML file, and loading it in your app?

Comment: @FrancoisNadeau That's something I didn't think of, and it sounds really good actually. I will give it a shot as soon as I get the chance to. Thanks a lot for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you can convert your document as an HTML file, and load it in a WebView.

Happy coding.